# Firebase Hosting - SSL certificate is pointing to another domain with same IP

Tags: ssl, firebase, dns, firebase-hosting

Since morning I am seeing problem with certificate on my custom domain connected to Firebase Hosting. It says my SSL certificate is for www.gimmegimme.gifts. This domain is unknown for me and I am not the owner. It seems it's the same IP address as my hosting is.

My devices are working fine but whenever I try to access custom domain website (www.monmaratelier.sk) with friend's phones/tablets/pc I am unable to even load - I just see SSL error. I guess SSL cert is cached.

**Unknown domain:** 
 gimmegimme.gifts - 151.101.1.195 - San Francisco

**My Firebase domain:** 
 monmar-1ddc0.firebaseapp.com - 151.101.1.195 - San Francisco

**Connected custom domain:**
 monmaratelier.sk -  151.101.1.195 / 151.101.65.195 - San Francisco

I don't see into problematic of networking/hosting/DNS/IP addresses conflict. I already tried contacting support.

What should I do? What could be the issue that Firebase URL directly is working fine but connect custom domain is not?

Comment: It can't be the same IP address unless either your ISP or its have made a huge mistake. Contact them both. Off topic.

Comment: I'm having the same problem since yesterday. I contacted my domain host who said the DNS records looked correct. I'm having the same ips as you but also 162.255.119.137 which as listed at http://ip-www.net/162.255.119.137 mentions it's being used by more than 100 websites. Not sure how that works. Just as for you the Firebase address works but not the custom domain. Let me know if you get it to work please!

Comment: It started working for me a few hours ago. Probably just DNS related. My domain host Namecheap mentioned that the 162... ip above was their server handling redirects and it was no longer in use, so most likely when they removed it recently, the DNS record wasn't updated and when I contacted them it was but took 24h before Firebase noticed it because of DNS latency. Working for you as well now?

Comment: @riper hi, i contacted Firebase support and they recommended reconnecting custom domain to Firebase. Quoting Firebase employee "There might be something wrong with the certificate. We might have to re-verify your custom domain, so that you will be provided a new certificate. To do this, please follow these simple steps below:
Remove all Firebase related records from your DNS records (TXT, A, CNAME)
Unlink/Delete your custom domain from your current project
After 5 to 10 minutes, re-verify your custom domain.
If this did not work, let me know."

It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting Firebase support they recommended me to reconnect custom domain because of issue with certificate.

After reconnecting custom domain everything worked as expected and still works to this day.